Determining if a set of vectors is a basis
Given a set of vectors in some space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ where
$$V = \{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$$
and $v_{n}$, $n=1,2,3$ is a column vector.
And we have a matrix $$A=(v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$$
Where $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix formed from the column vectors.
Is it enough to show that $|A| \neq 0$ to prove that the vectors form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or not ?
If yes, is it the same for a $3\times n$ matrix formed from $v_{1}, v_{2}, ... , v_{n}$

If $det(A) \neq 0$ then the vectors are linearly independent. We already knew that every basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has cardinality $3$, so we can conclude

Just a detail, but you should write ${v_1, v_2, v_3} \subseteq \mathbb R^3$, not $\in$.

${v_1,v_2,v_3} \in \mathbb R^9$, ${v_1,v_2,v_3} \not\in \mathbb R^3$,

The answer is yes for the $3 \times 3$ matrix, but for the $3 \times n$ question when $n \neq 3$ the matrix is not square, so you can't take the determinant.  But $\mathbb R^3$ is $3$-dimensional, so a basis must have $3$ vectors.  Hence when $n \neq 3$ you do not have a basis and don't need to bother with matrices.
